# Performance difference between assigning value to an Array Index and assigning value to Variable in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code where I am doing some calculations on array values and storing result back to array. Demo Code is as follows -

```
public class Test {
    private int[] x = new int[100000000];
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++) {
            t.testing(i);
        }
        System.out.println("time = " + (System.nanoTime() - start)/1000);
    }

    public void testing(int a) throws Exception {
        int b=1,c=0;
        if(b<c || b < 1) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid inputs");
        }
        int d= a>>b;
        int e = a & 0x0f;
        int f = x[d];
        int g = x[e];
        x[d] = f | g;
    }
 }
```

Main logic of program lies in

```
int d= a>>b;
int e = a & 0x0f;
x[d] = f | g;
```

When I test this code, it took 110ms.
But instead of assiging result back to x[d], if I assign it to a variable as

```
int h = f | g;
```

it took only 3 ms.

I want to assign result back to Array only, but it is hampering performance by big margin.
**This is a time critical program.**

So I want to know if there's any alternative to arrays in Java or any other way I can avoid this hampering?

I tested this code under default sun JVM config.

P.S. I tried UNSAFE API, but it isnt helping.

Comment: What about using a dictionary?

Comment: In what environment are you running this I wonder? That result you are getting seems highly unlikely to me. Measuring performance in Java requires that you first "warm up the JVM"; I would run the measuring three times and look at the figures of the third run through them.

Comment: @Gimby - I tested it after warming up as well, with aprroximately same results.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to beware of is the JVM optimising the code to nothing because it isn't doing anything useful.

In you case you are performing 100 million calls in 110 ms or about 1.1 nano-second per call.  Given a single memory to L1 cache access takes 4 clock cycles this is pretty fast.  In your test where you got 100 million in 3 ms, this suggests it is taking 0.03 nano-seconds per call or about 1/10th of a clock cycle.  To me this doesn't sound likely and I would expect that if the doubled the length of the loop it would still take 3 ms. i.e. you are timing how long it takes to detect and eliminate the code.

A basic problem you have is that you have an array which is 400 MB in size.  This will not fit in L1, L2 or L3 cache.  Instead it could be going to main memory and this typically takes 200 clock cycles.  The best option is to reduce the size of your array so it at least fits in your L3 cache.  How big is your L3 cache?  If it is say 24 MB, try reducing the array to just 16 MB and you should see a performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could be happening. First of all, try running each version of your program multiple times consecutively and averaging those. Secondly, assigning to an array in Java is a method call that performs error checking (such as throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when necessary). This is naturally going to be a bit slower than a variable assignment. If you have a really time-sensitive piece of code, consider using JNI for the numerical operations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/. This will often make your array logic faster.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `h` is a local variable and is allocated on the stack, whereas the array is stored in the main memory, which is way slower to write to.

Also note that, if this is really a high-performance application, you should put your main logic inside the for loop and avoid the overhead of calling a method. The instructions could be inlined for you, but you should not rely on it.

Comment: That seems like information based on how computers were 15 years ago. Things have changed since then.

Comment: Is stack memory not stored in main memory?  Why is stack memory faster to write to than heap memory?

Comment: @Brandon stack variables are more likely to exist entirely in a register.

Comment: @Gimby a downvote is not deserved when you don't know what you are talking about. The runtime can optimizie the code in a number of different ways. The stack area is not mapped to any physical location, thus in this case the compiler can (and will likely do) use processor registers to write the value. Or possibly skipping the writing entirely, since it has no side effects and it's never read